# SQL percentage of averages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, average

I have an SQL Server table `Table_1` with `name, subname, value` columns

For each subname i can get the average of the values by the query:

`select subname, AVG(value) as avg from Table_1 group by subname;`

I also can get the sum of values for each name:

`select name, sum(value) as sum from Table_1 group by name;`

I need the percentage of each `avg` row for each of the `name`, i cant figure this out.

EDIT: Eg. of percent would be -- average val1 is x% of the total avg values in a1

`select * from Table_1` looks like:

```
name subname value  
a1  val1    20  
a1  val2    20  
a1  val3    10  
a1  val1    40  
a1  val2    30  
a2  2val3   90   
a2  2val1   80  
a2  2val2   30  
a2  2val3   90   
a2  2val1   80  
a2  2val1   630
```

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: I think they're actually asking, "how should the output look like as data?", not the name of columns.

Comment: in this case, in a1, average of val1 is 30, average of val2 is 25, average of val3 is 10. Thus, percentages are val1= 30/(30+25+10) = 46%
So the result shows - a1 val1 46 .. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH data (name, subname, value) AS (
  SELECT 'a1',  'val1 ',   20  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1',  'val2 ',   20  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1',  'val3 ',   10  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1',  'val1 ',   40  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1',  'val2 ',   30  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val3',   90  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val1',   80  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val2',   30  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val3',   90  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val1',   80  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2',  '2val1',   630  
)
SELECT
  name,
  subname,
  percentage = AVG(value) * 100 / SUM(AVG(value)) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
FROM data
GROUP BY
  name,
  subname
;
```

Output:

```
name subname percentage
---- ------- -----------
a1   val1    46
a1   val2    38
a1   val3    15
a2   2val1   68
a2   2val2   7
a2   2val3   23
```

---

Useful reading:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: whoa! that's some complicated SQL for a SQL-n00b like me, but it works!

Comment: @heyNow: Aggregate window functions can often be very handy. And I think they are not that difficult to grasp! Take a look at the OVER Clause manual page for a start (the link's in my updated answer).